# Youtube Api's Private Videos

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-contacts-api, android-youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I have a scenario that, i have channel on youtube and I post a video as private. I have set permissions and invite to specific google email can see that video. how i can get that video using youtube apis by passing invited email.

I need process how I use to take a user email and private youtube video as inputs, and authorize just the specific user to view that video.

I want api example like below

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?key=googleKEY&maxResults=50&channelId=channelID&part=snippet&invited_email=sample@gmail.com

Thanks